# Can't find Tikz shadows.blur (MiKTeX 2.9)

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I try and compile this under MiKTeX 2.9:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I get an error

> I can't find file `tikzlibraryshadows.blur.code.tex'.

The obvious deduction would be that my version of TikZ is too old. But a) there is no mention of `shadows.blur` in the 2.10 manual and b) when I look in either of pgfCVS2012-11-04_TDS.tgz, pgf_2.10.tds.zip, I can't find any files whose name includes 'blur'.

What am I missing?

Comment: The `shadows.blur` library comes from [pgf-blur package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-blur)...

Comment: In fact they are all our experts' in-house brewed packages for example rather famous `hobby` library etc. You can find many more in https://code.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development

Comment: Thanks! Why is it that once I've installed it it works even without `usepackage{pgf-blur}`?

Comment: Probably It looks for the library (which has a particular name structure) and again probably it is in your working folder so it's always available.

Comment: As it's just a question about a specific file of a package and it's solved now, I close as too localized.

Comment: @Stefan. I had this exact same problem. I think anybody trying to follow an answer on this site based on shadows.blur is quite likely to run into the exact same problem. The question is perfect. The 'too localized' designation is overzealous.

Comment: @JamieVicary Maybe I closed it 3.5 years ago because it was flagged or voted for closing. That the solution was posted as a small comment, is also an indicator, that the issue is small and doesn't deserve a longer answer (if Paul thought otherwise, he would posted it as an answer, rather than a comment). Paul's comment could be made to an answer, possibly. The solution is here, helps somebody who looks for it, no further answer needed. But you can vote to reopen if you like.